# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shuffle'

Tags: python, nltk

I got this error while runing my code in python 2.6.6. And there is no issue while running in Python 3.4.3

```
usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py:319: UserWarning: Duplicate scores. Result may depend on feature ordering.There are probably duplicate features, or you used a classification score for a regression task.
      warn("Duplicate scores. Result may depend on feature ordering."
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "classification.py", line 31, in <module>
        main()
      File "classification.py", line 15, in main
        tm.optimaltrain(conf)
      File "/axp/gabm/npscnnct/dev/getThemes/textminer/textminer/classify.py", line 121, in optimaltrain
        score = self.cv(X,y,model)
      File "/axp/gabm/npscnnct/dev/getThemes/textminer/textminer/classify.py", line 140, in cv
        skf = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=self.cv_folds, shuffle=True)
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shuffle'
```

**Code:**

```
  def cv(self, X, y, model):
    y_true = []
    y_pred = []
    skf = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=self.cv_folds, shuffle=True)
    for train_index, test_index in skf:
      X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
      y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
      model.fit(X_train, y_train)
      y_pred += list(model.predict(X_test))
      y_true += list(y_test)
```

But when I remove the `Shuffle=True` from the code its runing fine. Modules I am using are scipy 0.11.0, nltk 2.0.1, sklearn 0.14.1

Please advice.
Thanks

Comment: Make sure you mark an answer as correct so that people looking at this in the future know what helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the source for your version (`0.14`) of `sklearn`: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.14.X/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L391

I've linked to the actual line for the **init** on `StratifiedKFold` - which shows that there is no `shuffle` keyword argument.

Upgrade to v `0.15`, which does have `shuffle` (as seen here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.15.X/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L399).

I'm going to assume that your version of `sklearn` on `Py3` is `0.15`?

Answer (score 2):

In sklearn 0.14, `cross_validation.StratifiedKFold()` has no keyword argument `shuffle`. Apparently, it was only added in a later version (0.15 actually).

You can either update sklearn or shuffle the input yourself (eg. with `random.shuffle()`) before stratification.